# Which environment for Talend Job Server

Tags: osgi, talend, apache-karaf

I am new to Talend Open Studio, and recently I want to apply it to my work.
I found that Talend Studio jobs can be run on OSGI runtime such as Apache Karaf.
But I still confuse that whether my jobs developed in Talend Data Integration Studio can be hosted in any OSGI runtime or they must be running on Talend Job Server.
Could someone explain me this one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ESB Runtime (Karaf container) is meant to deploy Webservices built in Talend ESB (SOAP or REST) or Routes (built with the camel components in the dedicated perspective).

Jobservers should be used to deploy standard DI Jobs.

Comment: If you are just using Talend Open Studio to build ETL jobs, it builds stand alone java, and can be run just as such, without needing anything more than the appropriate JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case you can also build a route and call a DataIntegration Job with the cTalendJob component either from the repository or exported as an OSGIBundle For ESB. For more information on how to build a Job and howto export a Job as an OSGI Bundle for ESB, see: https://help.talend.com/reader/HqPypUO_cLctKv_dAWcgFw/aleuaJ2WkXdRKd7BDi8R0w